# Firebase storage: check if user is admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a folder in Firebase storage that only the admin service account should be able to write to. (More particularly, that admin service account will only write to the storage from a cloud function).

I'd like to figure out how to create a rule that prevents any other user from writing to the storage bucket. Does anyone know how one can accomplish this goal?

I thought I could create a rule that forbid writing unless the writing agent's uid matched the admin uid, but I haven't been able to find the admin uid yet. I tried logging into my service account like so:

```
import firebase_admin, os
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app

if not len(firebase_admin._apps):
  cert = os.path.join('src', 'secrets', 'service-account.json')
  initialize_app(credentials.Certificate(cert), {
    'databaseURL': 'https://womp.firebaseio.com/',
    'storageBucket': 'womp.appspot.com/',
  })
```

then digging through the `firebase_admin._apps[0]` object to see if I could dig out a uid for the user, but no dice.

If others know how to create a rule that prevents any but admin users from writing to a storage instance, I'd be grateful for any insights they can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to limit access to service account using security rules.  Service accounts always bypass security rules.

Once you start working with service accounts, their access is controlled by Google Cloud IAM, which is completely different.  You can use IAM to limit which service accounts are allow to access a bucket, and that's going to operate completely independently of whatever security rules you write for end users going through the Firebase SDK.

If you don't want any users to write directly to a bucket, and only allow service account, the security rules for the bucket should simply reject all access.

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting on many fronts. I didn't realize any of this was the case! I guess I'll just "disable" write access to the path to be secured. Thanks very much!